# Automatic updating of query shown in a form based on dropdown selection

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I thought this was going to be the easiest question ever to solve, but after spending a morning searching for answers, I still can't get it to work.

I have a list box showing data for certain countries on a user form that is linked to a query. I want to allow my users to filer that list based on the selection in a dropdown.

This is the SQL in the list box row source:

```
SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblISIN_Country_Table.Country
FROM tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN
GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblISIN_Country_Table.Country, tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection
HAVING (((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country)=[Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry]) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

Both the values in the list box and the dropdown are displaying correctly. **However, I have not been able to get the dropdown selection to filter the list.**

So far I have tried inserting the following reference and various versions of it into the query that the list box links to in the row source:

```
[Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry]
```

I also inserted the following code for the `On Change` Event in the Dropdownlist:

```
Private Sub ddnCountry_Change()
    cmbFIlterSelection.Requery
End Sub
```

The `On Change` event fires correctly because when I set a breakpoint it stops on the one line of code, but it seems to do nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say `"I also inserted the following code"` however no code follows.

Comment: Sorry about that. My bad. Updated post.

Comment: Can you also post the SQL of the query used for your `ListBox`?

Comment: Updated above. Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: You should use a `WHERE`-clause instead of a `HAVING`-Clause since you do not use any aggregate functions in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After hours of looking for answers and now even posting on here, I found the problem:

The SQL Query needed to be modified to include the following `.Text`

Now it reads:

```
[Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text]
```

Comment: That kind of makes sense.  That means that you likely could also just put your event into the `AfterUpdate` as well and it should work without the `.Text` you really only need to use `.Text` whenever the value hasn't had the chance to update.

Comment: @Newd I just tried that... the `AfterUpdate` event works fine and it makes sense to me to use that in the future, but I still had to put `.Text` for it to work properly.

Comment: You had to use `.Text` in `AfterUpdate`?

Comment: Yup. Otherwise it failed. I am in fact still working on this particular problem, but it is no longer the issue that I have described here. I want the Listbox to show all possible records before the users start filtering it using the dropdown... I have a feeling I am going to be revisiting this exact question.