# How to show all items in Listbox that is linked to dropdown

Tags: ms-access-2010

In an Access Userform I have a listbox that is linked to a dropdown field. In the dropdown field the user can choose a country, and the listbox then updates and shows only the records that are relevant to that country.

I have described how I get the listbox to filter based on the selection in the dropdown in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891629/automatic-updating-of-query-shown-in-a-form-based-on-dropdown-selection/30892565?noredirect=1#comment49866916_30892565).

While I managed to solve one problem there I created another.

Now when I open the form, the listbox is empty instead of showing all records.

**My question: How can I show all records in the listbox to begin with and THEN have the user filter the list based on the dropdown?**

The SQL Code in the LIstbox is now the following:

```
SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblISIN_Country_Table.Country
FROM tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN
GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblISIN_Country_Table.Country, tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection
HAVING (((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country)=[Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text]) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this one as well... with a bit of help from an online article which I can now no longer find unfortunately (otherwise I would reference it here):

```
SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblISIN_Country_Table.Country
FROM tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN
GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblISIN_Country_Table.Country, tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection
HAVING (((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

The important part is this...

```
Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

Essentially the Nz function lets you return a value when a variant is null. I had it return `*` which ofcourse is the SQL equivalent of Return All.